# SVN co/list command asks private key passphrase each and every time in Ubuntu 16.04. Why?

Tags: svn, ssh, ubuntu-14.04, openssh, ubuntu-16.04

I did the following in Ubuntu 16.04

> eval `ssh-agent`
>
> ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
>
> Enter passphrase for ~/.ssh/id_rsa:......

key has been added successfully after the above step

> svn list svn+ssh://..................
>
> Enter passphrase for ~/.ssh/id_rsa:......
>
> svn co svn+ssh://....................
>
> Enter passphrase for ~/.ssh/id_rsa:......

while using the **svn list** or **co** command it asks private key passphrase each and every single time.
How to solve the above issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer the following link

https://www.gentoo.org/support/news-items/2015-08-13-openssh-weak-keys.html

i hope this will solve your problem

Comment: 404 Not Found when navigating to that link